# Is there a way to convert in date from character and the numeric data to factor in Databricks using R?

Tags: r, databricks, numeric

I have been using this code in R and it worked perfectly, but when I switched to Databricks platforms, it doesn't work. Anyone have any insights? The date in character format as "01--2-21", Plot_Num as numeric (101-108, 201-208, 301-308 t0 1-8), and year in numeric as 2019-2021 and it need to be changed to 1, 2, 3 as factor.

```
unifieddatasets$Date <- as.Date(unifieddatasets$Harvested, "%d-%b-%y")
unifieddatasets$Plot_Num <- as.factor(unifieddatasets$Plot_Num)
unifieddatasets$Year <- as.factor(unifieddatasets$Year)
**I tried this in Databricks but did not work** 
Unifieddatasets <- c(Plot_Num = "factor")
```

Comment: I do not get error but I get this (Named chr "factor"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "Plot_Num")

Comment: I think that is from the last statement.  i.e. `c(Plot_Num = "factor")` - a named vector with value as "factor" and name as Plot_Num. Can you print `str(unifieddatasets)`

Comment: data.frame': 278 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ Year                : int  1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Plot_Num            : int  303 306 306 102 102 102 306 203 305 203 ...
 $ Harvested           : chr  "3-Mar-20" "5-Jan-21" "5-Jan-21" "3-Dec-19" ...

Comment: Your code seems to be legit..  I am not sure about the use of last line of code

Comment: That's on databricks platform. I am new to this so do not know how to convert the numeric to factor. Its easy in Rstudio but the same code I use on data brick, it did not work,